# Parse : How to call a cloud method from an email?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, html-email, parse-cloud-code

When a user will sign-up in my app, application admin will get an email. Which will have two links, named "Approve Profile" or "Deny Profile" along with newly user details. The admin can choose any of the action (tap on a link from email app), then I would like to call a Parse cloud code method (along with some parameters) to handle approve or deny action for particular user.

Is it possible?

I was searching somewhere and found this,

https://[app-key]:javascript-key=[javascript-key]@api.parse.com/1/functions/[method_to_call]

We need to replace app-key/javascript key. Both is available in  Settings >> Keys of the app. And method which we'll have to call.

However when I call above url, it ask me username and password for my parse account. Even after entering the correct credentials its keep asking me the same thing again and again. Is it really working?

Or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [cloud code hosting](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#hosting) section in the guide.  You can use a myapp.parseapp.com domain or add CNAME to a domain you control for a custom name.  Once it is set up, you can deploy an Express app that does things like this:

```
// This is an example of hooking up a request handler with a specific request
// path and HTTP verb using the Express routing API.
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.render('hello', { message: 'Congrats, you just set up your app!'});
});
```

In the email message, include a link like:

```
http://myapp.parseapp.com/hello?email=jon@doe.org&somekey=somevalue
```

The params will be included in the Express request object.  There's no need to send any of your keys.